# Very old telefilm about an invisible monster

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

This is very very old, probably from the '80s, if not before. I happened to watch it several years ago and it is extremely probable it is a telefilm, part of some sort of series.

Unfortunately, only few details remain in my memory.

It is a science fiction - horror setting.

There is a movie crew that is filming a horror movie about an invisible monster that goes around killing people.

So, they are going to film a scene in a bedroom with an actor, and they tell him to lay in the bed, and after some time struggle a bit in a frantic way, and then lay still (all alone, since the monster is invisible, so the actor must fake the aggression).

Obviously (for us right now), when they check the actor, after the filming, they discover he is really dead, probably strangled but I don't remember.

Afterwards, they review the movie, I think on cinema screen and not on a monitor, and they see some strange white shadows hovering on the actor at the time of the attack.

Suddenly, while they are surprised, all the members of the crew die one by one, and the final scene is the cinema screen totally white with a shadow on it of some humanoid monster.

I think they called the monster a generic name, like the being, or the creature, or the thing.

Comment: "this is very very old, probably from the '80s"  --> Hmmm, I only know one  **very very old** movie from the [80s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roundhay_Garden_Scene).

Comment: Now I feel very, very old...

Comment: "very old, probably from the 80s" -- [cries in Millenial]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is episode seven of the 1973 television series *[The Evil Touch](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0069580/)*, episode titled: "[Seeing is Believing](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0876160/?ref_=ttep_ep7)".

The article below comes from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Evil_Touch).

> *The Evil Touch* is an Australian television series, originally broadcast in Australia and produced by Amalgamated Pictures Australasia in association with Olola Productions Australia. An anthology series, each episode had a self-contained story, usually in a thriller or horror style, and often with a twist ending. Subjects explored included the occult, science fiction, murder schemes, and whodunits. Each episode had a new cast of guest actors playing new characters, although several guest stars appeared in more than one episode.
>
> [...]
>
> The series was produced by American producer Mende Brown and partly funded by the Nine Network. A key feature was the involvement of internationally known actors. Some were lured to Australia to participate in the show by also being allowed to direct an episode. Supporting roles were filled by Australian actors. Although Australian television was still in black and white in 1973, to aid international marketability this series was shot entirely in colour, and on film.
>
> Each episode was introduced by Anthony Quayle who appeared in a darkened studio surrounded by unearthly golden smoke imagery, frequently reminding viewers that "there is a touch of evil in all of us". He returned to provide the epilogue to each installment, always wishing viewers "pleasant dreams".

I've added a link to the episode on YouTube.

Comment: This is it, thank you very much. It is totally different from what I remembered, sorry if I reported wrong details in my post.

Comment: @john_smith: No worries. It's extremely common on this site. :) I've had several cases myself where I misremembered the details.